# Firefox process has a long list of arguments looks suspicous

Tags: networking, firefox, security, browser, malware

Firefox has a config option (browser.tabs.remove.autostart.2) enabled by default. My Firefox was hanging, so I checked the process and it looked suspicious, so I verified the same with a new Firefox installation (but it looked ok). First, could some one confirm that below is genuine? also, what does intPrefs, boolPrefs, stringPrefs  arguments for?

```
    ubuntu   14891 21.7  3.6 2213104 295320 ?      Sl   22:23   0:09 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
    ubuntu   14945  4.4  1.9 1876248 153596 ?      Sl   22:23   0:01 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 1 -isForBrowser -intPrefs 5:50|6:-1|18:0|28:1000|34:20|35:5|36:10|45:128|46:10000|51:0|53:400|54:1|55:0|56:0|61:0|62:120|63:120|98:2|99:1|114:5000|124:0|126:0|137:10000|162:24|163:32768|165:0|166:0|174:5|178:1048576|179:100|180:5000|182:600|183:4|184:1|193:3|206:60000| -boolPrefs 1:0|2:0|4:0|26:1|27:1|30:0|33:1|37:1|38:0|39:0|40:0|43:1|44:1|47:0|48:0|49:0|50:0|52:0|57:1|58:1|59:0|60:1|64:1|65:1|66:0|67:1|68:1|69:0|70:1|73:0|74:0|77:1|78:1|82:1|83:1|84:1|85:0|86:0|88:0|89:0|90:1|91:0|92:1|95:1|97:0|100:1|101:0|108:0|113:0|116:0|118:1|119:1|121:1|125:0|127:0|129:0|131:1|132:1|138:1|139:0|140:1|142:0|153:1|160:0|161:0|164:1|167:0|169:1|171:1|172:0|177:0|181:1|186:0|187:0|188:0|189:1|190:0|191:1|192:1|195:1|198:0|199:0|200:1|201:1|202:0|203:1|204:1|205:1|207:0|208:0|210:0|218:1|219:1|220:0|221:0|222:0| -stringPrefs 3:7;release|96:0;|141:3;1.0|158:332;  ¼½¾ǃː??։֊׃״؉؊٪۔܁܂܃܄ᅟᅠ᜵           ???‐’․‧??????? ‹›⁁⁄⁒ ⅓⅔⅕⅖⅗⅘⅙⅚?⅜⅝⅞⅟∕∶⎮╱⧶⧸⫻⫽⿰⿱⿲⿳⿴⿵⿶⿷⿸⿹⿺⿻　。〔〕〳゠ㅤ㈝㈞㎮㎯㏆㏟꞉︔︕︿﹝﹞?．／｡ﾠ???￼�|159:4;high| -schedulerPrefs 0001,2 -greomni /usr/lib/firefox/omni.ja -appomni /usr/lib/firefox/browser/omni.ja -appdir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 14891 true tab
```

It is more readable below:

```
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox 
-contentproc 
-childID 1 
-isForBrowser 
-intPrefs 5:50|6:-1|18:0|28:1000|34:20|35:5|36:10|45:128|46:10000|51:0|53:400|54:1|55:0|56:0|61:0|62:120|63:120|98:2|99:1|114:5000|124:0|126:0|137:10000|162:24|163:32768|165:0|166:0|174:5|178:1048576|179:100|180:5000|182:600|183:4|184:1|193:3|206:60000| 
-boolPrefs 1:0|2:0|4:0|26:1|27:1|30:0|33:1|37:1|38:0|39:0|40:0|43:1|44:1|47:0|48:0|49:0|50:0|52:0|57:1|58:1|59:0|60:1|64:1|65:1|66:0|67:1|68:1|69:0|70:1|73:0|74:0|77:1|78:1|82:1|83:1|84:1|85:0|86:0|88:0|89:0|90:1|91:0|92:1|95:1|97:0|100:1|101:0|108:0|113:0|116:0|118:1|119:1|121:1|125:0|127:0|129:0|131:1|132:1|138:1|139:0|140:1|142:0|153:1|160:0|161:0|164:1|167:0|169:1|171:1|172:0|177:0|181:1|186:0|187:0|188:0|189:1|190:0|191:1|192:1|195:1|198:0|199:0|200:1|201:1|202:0|203:1|204:1|205:1|207:0|208:0|210:0|218:1|219:1|220:0|221:0|222:0| 

-stringPrefs 3:7;release|96:0;|141:3;1.0|158:332;  ¼½¾ǃː??։֊׃״؉؊٪۔܁܂܃܄ᅟᅠ᜵           ???‐’․‧??????? ‹›⁁⁄⁒ ⅓⅔⅕⅖⅗⅘⅙⅚?⅜⅝⅞⅟∕∶⎮╱⧶⧸⫻⫽⿰⿱⿲⿳⿴⿵⿶⿷⿸⿹⿺⿻　。〔〕〳゠ㅤ㈝㈞㎮㎯㏆㏟꞉︔︕︿﹝﹞?．／｡ﾠ???￼�|159:4;high| 
-schedulerPrefs 0001,2 
-greomni /usr/lib/firefox/omni.ja 
-appomni /usr/lib/firefox/browser/omni.ja 
-appdir /usr/lib/firefox/browser
```

Comment: What version of Firefox are you using?

Do you have any addons enabled? Also are you using Firefox from a PPA?

Finally, do you have another browser you on the system (such as Chrome) that you can check for suspect arguments? I personally don't think it's anything suspicious, but if there is anything suspicious going on it is hardly likely to affect a single browser unless it is based on a rogue addon.

Comment: version: 57.0.1 (64-bit), yes Firefox from PPA, No other Browser. I agree with you, but could you please explain the arguments. It looks unusual, doesn't it look unusual to you?

Comment: Looks quite normal. What the arguments mean I don't know and don't care -- the processes with the long command line arguments are obeyant children the master Firefox process, so those arguments are probably part of the interprocess communication protocol.

Comment: intPrefs, boolPrefs, stringPrefs

Comment: @muru I agree. Do you know of any reason to keep [that question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/971989/firefox-suspicious-subprocess-turned-out-to-be-legitimate-ff-behavior) closed as unclear? It seems quite clear to me; in particular, it is clear enough to close this question as a duplicate of it (which we would not ordinarily do for an actually-unclear original, except in cases of duplicate questions by the same author, which doesn't apply here).

Comment: @muru Yes, it is a similar concern. Solution asks to disable the feature. Still my question is what are these arguments for and why they look so unusual?

Comment: @EliahKagan Dunno, maybe worth reopening. @ Gaurav Firefox internal reasons? Study the code base. What's so unusual about a few preference maps?

Comment: @muru okay, I got it.